# What are the scenarios one should use isRequired for PropType vs defaultProps in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-proptypes

I constantly struggle to understand, when exactly should I be using `.isRequired` vs `.defaultProps={...}`
My thought is that, I think I should never ever really need to use isRequired, because it seems manually creating a bug that can break in the application because create isRequired automatically remove the need to add a corresponding default prop, that makes me feel uncomfortable just because it means I won't be able to expect a fail-safe value.

It definitely sounds an opinion based question, but I look for a better opinion that makes more sense if there is one.

Comment: `because it seems manually creating a bug that can break in the application` -- isRequired does not crash an application, it only throws a console error. It is a developer tool, and a good one.

Comment: You can't always provide a default value. For example when you have a component that renders information about a Person. The prop containing the person information must be supplied. You can't provide a default Person to show (that would be useless).

Comment: @Wazner well, true, but not true, I would say in that case I can supply at least an empty array if it expact an array of some sort, so I can have a fail safe to display error or whatever it should show

Comment: If that's a valid state your application can be in, I agree. But if you build your application around the fact that, that component is only rendered when there is a Person. Why should it need to handle the case where there isn't one?

Answer (score 3):

Using prop types is a good way of documenting the API for a component, so that other people know how it works without reading the code.

The way it's usually thought of is the component is guaranteed to render without errors if all the required props are supplied. The props that are not required would only enhance the component with additional functionality.

Consider this example

```
function UserCard({ name, avatarUrl }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      {avatarUrl && <img src={avatarUrl} />}
    </div>
  );
}

UserCard.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  avatarUrl: PropTypes.string
};
```

Now, if you want to render a default profile picture if it's not supplied, you could remove the conditional check inside the component and provide a default value instead.

```
function UserCard({ name, avatarUrl }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <img src={avatarUrl} />
    </div>
  );
}

UserCard.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  avatarUrl: PropTypes.string
};

UserCard.defaultProps = {
  avatarUrl: "/assets/generic-picture.png"
};
```

Comment: let's say we are writing like this 
` 
function UserCard({ name, avatarUrl =  "/assets/generic-picture.png" }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <img src={avatarUrl} />
    </div>
  );
}
 `
Would I still need defaultProps? just curious

Comment: @LusanDas, long story short, no - you wouldn't need defaultProps in that case. You could just use default values with destructing instead.